# mvc .htaccess disable changing url if directory exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess file code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

It send the url as a parameter to index.php. The problem that i have is when i type in a directory such as site.com/admin everything works but the url gets changed in the address bar to site.com/admin/?url=admin. How do i disable that extra part from showing up. I don't want to rename all my directories.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because directory slash is turned on, and you need to turn it off:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

As long as you are routing directories that exist straight to your index.php file, it's ok to turn it off. What it does is it redirects requests for directories that exist but *do not have a trailing slash* to the same thing with a trailing slash. Problem is that both mod_dir and mod_rewrite get applied to the same request, so the mod_dir redirect is applied, then mod_rewrite mangles the URI, *and then* the redirect is fired off at the end of the processing pipeline.

Comment: this is what i was looking for thanks. Wish you said this in the other thread.

Comment: @Avovk didn't understand what you were asking in a one line comment.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid rewriting directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also make sure you don't have any other conflicting .htaccess in your system.